# Fail to send emails with SMTPJS and Mailgun

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple form and I am trying to send emails.

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendEmail() {
      alert("Submitting form...");
      Email.send({
        Host: "smtp.mailgun.org",
        Username: "postmaster@sandbox000000000000000cdba.mailgun.org",
        Password: "som-password-thing",
        To: 'myaddress@gmail.com',
        //From: document.getElementById("form_email").value,
            From: "thisisthefromaddress@gmail.com",
        Subject: "Website Form Submission",
            Body: "this is body"
        //Body: document.getElementById("form_name").value + " - " + document.getElementById("form_message").value,
      })
        .then(function (message) {
          alert("Form Successfully Submitted. Thank You.")
        });
    }
  </script>
```

There are no errors, but the page reloads and no email is sent, it also doesnt get to the last alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form should look like this

```
<form onsubmit="sendEmail">
...
</form>
```

and your function should look like this

```
function sendEmail(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

By default, a form submission will redirect the page (this is how web pages used to make modifications without js). By calling `event.preventDefault()`, you stop this default behavior.

Comment: Thanks - it now executes all the code, but the email is still not sending...

Comment: I'd try a few things. First, I'd add `.then( ... ).catch(e => console.log(e))` and see if there are any errors on the console. If not, I'd check the network logs in the browser's debugger to see what happened on the response. Then, I'd check the logs in mailgun. If all that's good, I'd contact support. In this case, I have a hunch this is a CORS issue, or you need to do some authorization for the `To` and `From` addresses to send properly.